# How to precompile a ColdFusion application under Websphere/Solaris 10

Tags: coldfusion, websphere, solaris-10

I am in the process of installing a ColdFusion application on Solaris 10 64-bit (Sparc) running with WebSphere 6.1. The cfcompile script that comes with CF makes a reference to jrun.jar however this library is not available when CF is installed as an ear file. An abstract of cfcompile.sh is the following:

```
su $cfuser -c "${_JAVACMD} -cp $CLASSES -Dcoldfusion.classPath=$CFUSION_HOME/lib/updates,$CFUSION_HOME/lib -Dcoldfusion.libPath=$CFUSION_HOME/lib coldfusion.tools.CommandLineInvoker Compiler -cfroot $CFUSION_HOME -webinf $WEBINF -webroot $webroot $dir"
```

Do you see ways to solve this problem (that is to precompile an application), besides installing CF as a standalone running on JRUN server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the contents of the EAR file?  There should be a WAR file, in which you'll find WEB-INF/lib.  It may be in there.  If so, extract it and place it on the classpath.

EAR/WAR file are just zip compressed archives.

This is just a "best guess" on my part.

HTH

Comment: Hi! That is exactly what I did but in the exploded version there is no jrun.jar. This file is available only when you install CF as a standalone version. I simply want to have a sourceless and precompiled deployment option but till now I do not see it possible without JRUN.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install in stand-alone mode on some other temporary location (preferably the same OS & version), and copy jrun.jar to where you want it to be, on the permanent home of the application?

Answer (score 0):

I created my own version of cfcompile.sh on-site to work on the client's infrastructure. The most important part is to have a correct reference to j2ee.jar (found in WAS distribution).